# PHP array merge values from one array into another

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry I have read so many posts to make sense of this and have finally confused myself!

I have 2 arrays:

Array 1:

```
Array (

[0] => Array ( [ID] => SI012348 [Date] => 06/01/2016 [Month] => 1 [Tier1] => 2.188875 [Tier2] => [Tier3] => [Tier4] => [Delivery] => 0 ) 

[1] => Array ( [ID] => SI012351 [Date] => 06/01/2016 [Month] => 1 [Tier1] => 2.139 [Tier2] => 0 [Tier3] => 0 [Tier4] => 0 [Delivery] => 0 ) 

[2] => Array ( [ID] => SI012387 [Date] => 14/01/2016 [Month] => 1 [Tier1] => 0.201 [Tier2] => 0 [Tier3] => 0 [Tier4] => 0 [Delivery] => 0 ) 

)
```

Array 2: (Contains all invoices with Delivery charges)

```
Array ( 
[SI000005] => 25 
[SI000010] => 15 
[SI000054] => 20 
[SI000069] => 0 
[SI000074] => 20 
[SI000076] => 16
)
```

I need to update Array 1 where SI00000x matches and push the value from Array 2 into the [Delivery] value in Array 1.

I am sure this is straightforward but everything I try either takes an age or crashes!

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this (note the [ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769288/php-ampersand-before-the-variable-in-foreach-loop)):

```
foreach ($arr1 as &$rec) {
    if (isset($arr2[$rec['ID']])) $rec['Delivery'] = $arr2[$rec['ID']];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (use a reference)

```
foreach ($array1 as &$a1) {
  if(isset($array1[$a1['ID']])) $a1['Delivery'] = $array1[$a1['ID']];
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array1 as &$a1) {
    if (isset($array2[$a1['ID']])) {
        $a1['Delivery'] = $array2[$a1['ID']];
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated. The changes will persist outside the loop.